# Subsetting and correlating two matrix of different sizes having 'NA'

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, subset

I have two different sizes matrix with 'NA' values and want to find out correlation between the common terms. e.g. if,

```
d1 =
       [x]  [y]   [z]
    a    1    6   11
    b    2   NA   12
    c    3    8   13
    d    4    9   14
    p+q  5   10   15

d2 =
   [t]  [u]  [v]  [x]  [y]
p+a 20   16   12    8    4
b   19   15   11    7    3
c   18   14   10    6    2
a   17   13    9    5    1
```

The row names may have some special character as well (e.g +). I want to subset both matrix so that they  have only common rows and columns, without NA, such as,

```
d1 <-  
    [x]  [y] 
[a]  1    6
[c]  3    8

d2 <-
   [x]  [y] 
[a]  5   1
[c]  6   2
```

and i can perform cor(d1,d2). I am not interested in using `use` or `na.rm` option of `cor`
Actaully, the real data is in thoudands of rows and columns. I tired `complete.cases` and `is.na` to find and remove NA . Then I tried `%in%` to filter the rows and columns but i am getting NA or NaN as final answer.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 r1 <- intersect(rownames(d1), rownames(d2))
 c1 <- intersect(colnames(d1), colnames(d2))
 indx1 <- !!rowSums(is.na(d1)) 
 r2 <- r1[!r1 %in% names(indx1)[indx1]]

 d1[r2,c1]
 #  x y
 #a 1 6
 #c 3 8

 d2[r2,c1]
      x y
 #  a 5 1
 #  c 6 2
```